# make an scp as apache in symfony2 script

Tags: apache, symfony, scp

I have a question about scp and apache user between local and destination hosts.

In my computer, i have created a folder .ssh in /var/www/ and i have generated a rsa key for www-data user.

Next, i have copied id_rsa.pub content to authorized_key file on destination server.

When i make a scp like this sudo -u www-data scp somefile.php root@destination_ip:/home/, it works.

But i'm using this in symfony script.

```
$process = new Process('scp somefile.jpg root@destination_ip:/home/');
$process->setTimeout(3600);
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {

   throw new \RuntimeException($process->getErrorOutput());
}
```

But exception is thrown with message Host key verification failed.

I don't understand why.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh2 php library and copy the file via ssh2_scp_send command. About this command, check php manual ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

An example code may be ...

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'username',
                          '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
                          '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa', 'secret')) {
  echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n";
} else {
  die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}
ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/somefile.jpg', '/remote/somefile.jpg', 0644);
```

Comment: I have used ssh2_connect and ssh2_sftp and it works. I have created a backup specific user for security (not root of course).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the user that runs the apache process is not the root, and is not authorised to do connect to that server. Check with user is running your apache (usually www-data?, try `ps aux | grep apache`) and then from the command-line:

```
sudo su www-data
scp somefile.jpg root@destination_ip:/home/
```

If it asks you for the password, you will need to do copy the ssh key from the www-data user. Probably `ssh-copy-id root@destination_ip` would work, and then retrying the scp command should work. Note that you might need to generate the ssh-keys for the www-data user.